# Gutenberg Editor Width and Height for Blocks

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm writing a Gutenberg editor block plugin and I need the width and height of the Gutenberg editor (only the editor part) to make the block full width and height if the user asks for it.

I started writing the javascript for it and I can get the width and height from the element with class edit-post-layout__content. But it depends on other elements such as the sidebar open and close.

I found some CSS code that makes the block full width but they are actually 100vw with calc in it, and when used, the block goes under sidebars (left and right).

Is there a hook or some function that I can use to get the width and height of the element inside my render function for Gutenberg block?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I've just based it on the class `wp-block-post-content`. What I've done is created a JavaScript function that accepts a style, and converts any "vw" measurements into "px":

```
function viewport_units_conversion( value ) {
    // Calculate vw into pixels
    var builder_width = document.getElementsByClassName("wp-block-post-content")[0].clientWidth;
    var regex = /([\d\.]+)vw/g;
    value = value.replace( regex, function(match, number) {
        return ( builder_width / 100 * number ) + "px";
    });
    return value;
}
```

You can adapt this to also accept "vh" and work it out from the `clientHeight`, however as the height is not much smaller than the viewport height itself, we didn't bother with it.

If you collapse any of the sidebars or resize the window, then the values may require re-calculating, but this occurs when you simply click on any element with these in.

I'm unaware of any hooks that will do this for you, but if there is, then that will most likely be a better approach.